# Maven multi module+RestJersey2+Spring3 - No Class Definition Found Exception

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to create a REST API with each classes/layers as a different modules. So created a multi module maven project+RestJersey2+Spring3. Even after adding the dependencies in the respective pom.xml am getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" when I try to add the project and run in my tomcat server. The following is my project settings and details:

My parent project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>danfoss.des.api.version</groupId>
<artifactId>desservicepoc</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>desservicepoc Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<modules>
    <module>resourceModulePoc</module>
    <module>webapp</module>
    <module>businessModulePoc</module>
</modules></project>
```

My first child module (webapp):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<parent>
    <groupId>danfoss.des.api.version</groupId>
    <artifactId>desservicepoc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>danfoss.des.api.version</groupId>
<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>webapp Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>danfoss.des.api.version</groupId>
  <artifactId>resourceModulePoc</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>danfoss.des.api.version</groupId>
        <artifactId>businessModulePoc</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hk2</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <!-- <exclusion>
            <artifactId>bean-validator</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
        </exclusion> -->
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
  <build>
<finalName>webapp</finalName>
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-
class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>despocservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-
class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>danfoss.des.api.resources</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>despocservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="danfoss.des.api.resources.*" />

 </beans>
```

My second child(resourceModulePoc):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>danfoss.des.api.version</groupId>
    <artifactId>desservicepoc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>resourceModulePoc</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>danfoss.des.api.version</groupId>
        <artifactId>businessModulePoc</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>
                    jersey-container-servlet-core
                </artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hk2</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>sky-sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>skysql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
        <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.3.0.603</version>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
 </properties>
</project>
```

Java class (Resource class - entry point of my service)

```
package danfoss.des.api.resources.v1;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import danfoss.des.api.business.v1.BusinessHandler;

@Singleton
@Named
@Path("/v1/sites")
public class Resource {

BusinessHandler businessHandler;

public Resource(){
}

@Autowired
public Resource(BusinessHandler testBusinessHandler){
    this.businessHandler = testBusinessHandler;
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response pingService() {
    String success = "Service 1 is up and running";
    businessHandler.testBusinessHandler();
    return Response.status(200).entity(success).build();
}
}
```

My third child module(businessModulePoc)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>danfoss.des.api.version</groupId>
<artifactId>desservicepoc</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>businessModulePoc</artifactId>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>
                    jersey-container-servlet-core
                </artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hk2</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
       </dependency>
      </dependencies>
  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
  <build>
    <finalName>businessModulePoc</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Java class (Second layer):

```
package danfoss.des.api.business.v1;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class BusinessHandler {

public void testBusinessHandler(){
    System.out.println("Business Handler 1 is invoked");
}
}
```

Error Console:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of 
class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: danfoss/des/api/business/v1/BusinessHandler
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.
AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors
(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.
determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.
getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.
getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.
doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.
getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.
finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.
refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.
configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.
initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.
contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart
(StandardContext.java:4994)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal
(StandardContext.java:5492)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call
(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call
(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
danfoss.des.api.business.v1.BusinessHandler
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass
(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass
(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
... 27 more

WARNING: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 
'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root 
WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Jun 26 02:20:07 IST 2017]; root of 
context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.
getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.
doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:966)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.
close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.
closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.
contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop
(StandardContext.java:5035)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal
(StandardContext.java:5687)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call
(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call
(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Have added the screen shots of the error which am getting my console while starting my server and my project structure as well:
[NoClassDefinitionFound Error Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8KuF.png)
[My Multi Module Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtrZ1.png)

Please let me know where exactly am going wrong or if I am missing something in my configuration. Have tried a lot of links for references still facing NoClassDefinitionFoundException in my console when I try to start my server.

Comment: your stack trace picture is not clear, can you post as code?

Comment: @Generic..Have added my error console as code for your reference.